# https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/ not connected. retrying

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to work out query access to the Google Analytics API.  I am not a developer and so progressing via the developer route is currently not an option (notes - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide).

I have been looking at setting up with BigQuery, but am struggling to check that I can query in the web interface because it will not load for me.

I am logged in with the account that I am using to access our company URL (I can access this perfectly well using the GA interface).

I can also query the http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ interface successfully.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to go the whole hog and set up the bigquery billing (I am hesitant to do this since I want to prove the concept first).

Regards

Tristan

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/, then I would work with your system administrator to verify that you have network connectivity to that web site.

If you can access the [BigQuery UI](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/), then you can follow the [Sign Up for BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/sign-up) instructions to enable the UI for you. You do not need to sign up for billing to run a few queries over the public sample tables, but you do need to sign up for billing if you want to load your own data into the system and to significantly increase your query quota limits.

As to BigQuery integration with Google Analytics Premium (see the [blog post](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2013/05/io-announcement-google-analytics.html) for background on this feature), you need to request this integration through Google Analytics Premium. Please contact your Google Analytics Premium customer support.